# Display Drop-down box next to countries text

Tags: javascript, css

Please vist [link](http://sb1.collagekingapp.com/) you can see on top left , "country: " &
below that there is dropdown box.

[image]

1)I want to move that dropdown box next to "country:" , I can use `top:5px;lefdt:140px;`

But I don't think it is good css practice.

2)Also I want to give some space after countries name &

3)when we mouse-over on particular country, it should show different color.

I want as like below image :

[image]

**css**

```
select#select-language {
    position: absolute;
    top: 30px;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

**script**

```
<script>

jQuery(document).ready(function () {
  jQuery('select#select-language').hover(function () {
    jQuery(this).attr('size', jQuery('option').length);
  }, function () {
    jQuery(this).attr('size', 1);
  });
});

</script>
```

**php**

```
 <?php if(count($this->getStores())>1): ?>
<div class="form-language">
    <label for="select-language"><?php echo $this->__('Country:') ?></label>
    <select id="select-language" title="<?php echo $this->__('Your Language') ?>" onchange="window.location.href=this.value">
    <?php foreach ($this->getStores() as $_lang): ?>
        <?php $_selected = ($_lang->getId() == $this->getCurrentStoreId()) ? ' selected="selected"' : '' ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $_lang->getCurrentUrl() ?>"<?php echo $_selected ?>><?php echo $this->escapeHtml($_lang->getName()) ?></option>
    <?php endforeach; ?>
    </select>
</div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Moving it to inline with the country,

this should do it

```
select#select-language {
    position: relative;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

2. The hover effect changing the size="1" to "5" doesn't look like a good method to approach that. I would recommend user clicking on the dropdown without hover.
3. If you want different colors on hover, you could add a class in a span element encapsulating the option text and assigning colors with pseudo :hover in css with your desired color. If you change hover as like the point 2 above i have mentioned, the selection highlight will be rendered automatically by the browser.

Comment: please check updated JS code, when i chnage size from 1 to 5, it increased the length. can you please help for width ?

Comment: also can you please check code and update the answer for adding different color on mouse-over countires.

Comment: Why are you changing size="1" to "5" ? Can;t you use select dropdown and not doing the one you are doing?

Comment: i reverted back . now only problem is it worked fine. when we hover mouse than it will display dropdown , after that when hover mouse other place on site, `drop down box should disappear`. but now its displaying all time. once we refresh page, than only its disappearing.

Answer (score 1):

```
  select#select-language {
    position: absolute;
    top: 30px;
    z-index: 2;
    margin-top: -2em;
    margin-left: 4em;
    padding-right: 2em;
}
 option:hover {
    color: white;
    background: red;
}
```

Comment: it worked fine , can you please help me for giving spaces after countries and for changing color of particular country when we mouse over on it.

Comment: it worked fine. when we hover mouse than it will display dropdown , after that when hover mouse other place on site,

`drop down box should disappear`. but now its displaying all time.

Comment: it should disappear only if we refresh the page.

Comment: @spylh9999ggr in my code it work fine. please add only my css (for this 2 css) remove other css for this. if possoble.

Comment: yes, i updated only your  code, if you found any other code, please tell me i will remove it. yes i updated code in site.

Comment: but the background- color should extend until the last, now its covering only countries name.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110975/discussion-between-dkc007-and-spylh9999ggr).

Answer (score 1):

```
select#select-language {
    position: absolute;
    top: 30px;
    margin-top: -2em;
    margin-left: 4em;
```

Comment: it worked fine , can you please help me for giving spaces after countries and for changing color of particular country when we mouse over on it

Comment: everything solved, now  the background- color should extend until the last, now its covering only countries name.